How to obtain one study effect from several within-study effects?
I want to do a narrative review (as a meta-analysis is not possible), and I want to conclude per study whether the predictor was significant yes/no. However, studies have several effect sizes per predictor. For example, I want to investigate parental psychopathology as a predictor, and one study investigated both parental depression and parental substance use. From the two measures I want one conclusion (for this study). How can I get to one effect size or conclusion per study?
Can I assume if both were non significant the parental psychopathology predictor is non significant? And in that case, what if 1 out of 2 was significant? Or 3 out of 4?
I have also tried to do a meta-analysis within one study with several effect sizes, but I found those results to be questionable. For example, a study with 4 non significant effect sizes became significant:
data <- data.frame(logOR = c(1.41098697371026, 1.14740245283754, 1.61938824328727, 0.470003629245736), #log transformed Odds Ratio
           CI.low_log = c(-0.127833371509885, -0.941608539858445, -0.462035459596559, -2.30258509299405), #log transformed lower bound
           CI.high_log = c(2.95386806945529, 3.23867845216438, 3.69907727909038, 3.27374272630904), # log transformed upper bound
           vi = c(0.618029191694011, 1.1372084115782, 1.12679998074128, 2.02359901787885), # squared standard error, ((data$CI.high_log - data$CI.low_log)/3.92)^2
           effect_id = 1:4
)


rma.mv(
     yi = logOR,           # Log-transformed OR
     V = vi,               # Variance
     random = list(~ 1 | effect_id), 
                           # Random effects structure
     data = data
 )

Multivariate Meta-Analysis Model (k = 4; method: REML)

Variance Components:

            estim    sqrt  nlvls  fixed     factor 
sigma^2    0.0000  0.0000      4     no  effect_id 

Test for Heterogeneity:
Q(df = 3) = 0.4697, p-val = 0.9255

Model Results:

estimate      se    zval    pval   ci.lb   ci.ub    
  1.2790  0.5077  2.5191  0.0118  0.2839  2.2742  * 

---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1


The model you are fitting is a standard random-effects model that assumes independent estimates. It does not account for the fact that the 4 estimates are presumably computed for the same study participants and hence that p-value cannot be trusted.

Yes I understand that is the issue with this approach, but I don't know how to control for this

You would need the covariance between the estimates. To compute this, you would need the primary data of the study or you would have to guestimate the correlation between the estimates.

I'm unclear why - if a proper meta-analysis is not possible - you would do a narrative review, but then care about whether things are significant. "Significant vs. not" is a very noisy random variable that is influenced by not just whether there is a true underlying effect, but also exactly how it is measured (you gave two kind of very different questions that to some extent address the same construct), how much data there are in the study and so on. You can look at that as doing the same thing as a meta-analysis, but making it harder by throwing information away (dichotomizing into yes/no) and mixing in extra noise (things like sample size suddenly randomly shake things up). Would it not make sense to describe what was seen in each study and try to describe general trends rather than focussing on whether the random variable that is a p-value is <=0.05 or >0.05?
Additionally, what's wrong with multiple outcomes from the same study when taken in combination providing a lower p-value than each outcome on its own? It's not like significant vs. not is somehow some magical boundary and the difference of significant vs. not significant is not in itself "significant". In fact, combining multiple endpoints like this may be a very sensible approach, you just need to reflect different sources or variability (and correlations) appropriately. Obviously, things will randomly (and non-randomly, as there might be systematic differences) vary from study to study, from outcome/question to each other, but also different assessments on the same study participants within a study will be correlated. As long as your analysis were to reflect that, that might be a promising avenue to explore.
